# Have XCode set the @executable_path where to look for a dylib automatically

Tags: xcode, dylib, install-name-tool

I build my OSX application using XCode 5.1.1 and link to a .dylib.
I've set up Build Phases -> Copy Files to copy the .dylib in the Frameworks destination.

When I launch from XCode it works fine, but when I double-click launch the .app bundle from Finder, it complains it cannot find the dylib, which XCode has dutifully placed under Contents/Frameworks, which can be easily verified in finder.

otool -L on my executable reveals that it is looking for

```
@loader_path/libXYZ.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

I can hack around this easily by using install_name_tool on my executable as follows:

```
install_name_tool -change @loader_path/libXYZ.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libXYZ.dylib  my_exec
```

but that change is lost on each re-build obviously. How can I tell XCode to set up the @executable_path../Frameworks in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Run Script Phase to the Build Phases.

Comment: How do I cd to the folder where the application is at?